# fitnesse variable in suite

Tags: java, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim, selenium-fitnesse-bridge

I'm facing a problem with Fitnesse.

I have the following testcase with these steps.

1. Generate XML
2. send xml
3. read answer
4. return property from answer

I have another testcase that should use that return value.

Can I set a global variable that I can use in my whole testsuite? (Btw the return value is variable)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I have another testcase that should use that return value."* In general: this is a bad test design. Don't create tests which depends on other tests. If you need to data for testing a certain case, then retrieve that data in the test method, even if you've done that before for a different test.

Comment: Are you using Slim of Fit? I just noticed your tags. So I assume Slim.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bit design-smell to pass data between tests. But maybe there is a good reason for doing so in your situation. If it is done in a SuiteSetUp or SetUp it might more expected.

You can store the property in a [Slim Symbol](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.SymbolsInTables) and read that property in the other test. Or, least preferred approach, you can create your own static variable in a fixture and pass data using that.